# Error with Ajax-Enabled WCF Service (JSON) when consuming from jquery .ajax()

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

Unfortunately it only hits the error condition when calling .ajax() and textStatus (2nd param) only says "error".  I've read through several examples and other questions on stackoverflow but must be missing something.  Thanks in advance for any help.

**WCF Service:**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://localhost/")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Items
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World.";
    }
}
```

**WCF Web.config**

Pertinent parts only...
Services:

```
<services>
  <service name="OService.ReadServices.Items">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="OService.ReadServices.Items"/>
    <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="OService.ReadServices.Items"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Behaviors:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://localhost/OService/ReadServices/Items.svc/json/HelloWorld",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("success: " + msg.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown + " - " + xhr);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Check response in FireBug (Firefox addmin)

Answer (score 2):

This reply is kind of late, but you defined your web method as a `[WebGet]` but call it as a `POST` request in your Jquery Ajax method. Replace the `[WebGet]` with something like:

`[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]`.

Comment: First, +1 for replying after so long... unfortunately, I am no longer using this type of code as I've moved on to using WebApi, so I can't test the original issue, but I agree with your reply it seems as though that would fix it - I don't think I even realized I had POST in the javascript call at the time.